# Customize the nested data in Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a ModelSerializer:

```
class WorkOrderRetrieveSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    workordercomments = WorkOrderCommentForWorkOrderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        fields = "__all__"
```

The JSON data is bellow:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "workordercomments": [
    .....

        {
            "id": 21,
            "content": "test files",
            "files": "[71]",
            "ctime": "2018-01-11T11:03:17.874268+08:00",
            "uptime": "2018-01-11T11:03:17.874362+08:00",
            "workorder": 1,
            "comment_user": {
                "id": 5,
                "username": "test03",
                "is_admin": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "workorder_num": "WON15118747168252",
    "name": "order01",
    "content": "first conntetn",
    "workordertype": "teck",
    "workorder_status": "created",
    "user_most_use_email": "lxas@128.com",
    "server_id": null,
    "public_ip": null,
    "belong_area": null,
    "files": null,
    "ctime": "2017-11-28T21:11:56.826971+08:00",
    "uptime": "2017-11-28T21:11:56.827064+08:00",
    "to_group": 3,
    "user": 2
}
```

The `"files": "[71]",` in my JSON is a string of a group contains file `id`s.

`workordercomments` is the related-name of the workorder.

I want in the JSON `workordercomments` shows the `files` like this:

```
        {
            "id": 21,
            "content": "test files",
            "files": "['/media/images/xxxxx.png']",
            "ctime": "2018-01-11T11:03:17.874268+08:00",
            "uptime": "2018-01-11T11:03:17.874362+08:00",
            "workorder": 1,
            "comment_user": {
                "id": 5,
                "username": "test03",
                "is_admin": true
            }
        }
```

The "files" value I want to is the link rather than its `id`.

```
"files": "['/media/images/xxxxx.png']",
```

or

```
"files": ['/media/images/xxxxx.png'],
```

Is it possible to customize the format? should I come true what function in serializer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a custom serialzier, as per the docs, and override the default values generated by ModelSerializer.

For example:

```
from rest_framework.fields import Field

class FileRelatedField(RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return instance.file_path # or whereever that path comes from


class WorkOrderRetrieveSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        fields = '__all__'

    files = FileRelatedField(
        many=True, 
        source='file_set.all'
    )
```

Depending on how your `__str__` value is on your File model, you can maybe do this:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import StringRelatedField

class WorkOrderRetrieveSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        fields = '__all__'

    files = StringRelatedField(
        many=True, 
        source='file_set.all'
    )
```